# R bs4dash fresh package doesn't work properly

Tags: r, shiny, bs4dash

According to the documentation in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fresh/vignettes/vars-bs4dash.html

bs4dash_status(light = "red") should render a red background in the navbar.  However, it doesn't.  It still remains white.  Any thoughts as to why?

I can put bs4dash_color(white = "red") and that will change the navbar background, but it changes other things as well, which I don't really want.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(fresh)

theme1 = create_theme(
    bs4dash_sidebar_light(bg  =  "green"),
    bs4dash_layout(),
    
    bs4dash_status(primary = "#5E81AC", danger = "#BF616A", light = "red"),
    bs4dash_layout(main_bg = "#353c42"),
    bs4dash_color(gray_900 = "#FFF"),   # white = "#272c30" changes the border and sidebar and footer
    bs4dash_status(light = "red"),

    bs4dash_vars(main_footer_bg = "purple",
                 navbar_light_color = "#bec5cb",
                 navbar_light_active_color = "#FFF",
                 navbar_light_hover_color = "#FFF")
)


ui = dashboardPage(
    
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(skin = "light"),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(),
    footer = dashboardFooter(),
    body = dashboardBody(use_theme(theme1))
)

server = function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old but I came across it trying to fix the same problem.  I found that if you create the css file using the fresh package like such:

```
create_theme(
    bs4dash_sidebar_light(bg  =  "green"),
    bs4dash_layout(),
    
    bs4dash_status(primary = "#5E81AC", danger = "#BF616A", light = "red"),
    bs4dash_layout(main_bg = "#353c42"),
    bs4dash_color(gray_900 = "#FFF"),   # white = "#272c30" changes the border and sidebar and footer
    bs4dash_status(light = "red"),

    bs4dash_vars(main_footer_bg = "purple",
                 navbar_light_color = "#bec5cb",
                 navbar_light_active_color = "#FFF",
                 navbar_light_hover_color = "#FFF"),
output_file = "www/myCustomFresh.css"
)
```

you can then go into the file and change the value yourself. Open in a text editor and find ".navbar-white" and change the background-color to red: ".navbar-white{background-color:red}".  Then in your UI you have :

```
body = dashboardBody(use_theme("myCustomFresh.css"))
```

Hope this helps others that were stuck like me.

Comment: Hi so how does this exactly works? Cause im trying to change status colors with bs4dash_status but doesnt work. Do you mean I have to change by hand in the css file? What does the first thing of your code do than (the bs4Dash stuff.)?.

Comment: The bs4dash stuff is used to create the colors of the different dashboard elements. The last line "output_file = "www/myCustomFresh.css"" creates a Fresh's css file in the www subfolder.  Then, yes, you have to change the values by hand in that file and link it to the app with "use_theme".  In the problem above, we just had to change the navbar element in the css.

Comment: Right but whats the point of first addidng colours via bs4dash if you need to change them manually? Cant you just work with the css file from the beginning? That part I dont understand

Comment: You can directly modify a css file from the start.  When I worked with fresh and bs4dash, creating a theme seemed to work with everything but the navbar.  So we could still create the style we wanted with the fresh package but just had to manually edit that value in the css file.